# What is the location of log file for sublime text 2 on Mac OSX

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm trying figure out why JSON syntax highlighting seem to work sometimes but not always. Is there a log which sublime text 2 logs to?

Comment: The syntax highlighting is just a series of regex matches that apply a scope. The scopes then map to colors. You should try to identify what pattern is causing the incorrect syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the console by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> (that's the button to the left of <kbd>1</kbd> and above <kbd>Tab</kbd>on US keyboards) in Windows/Linux, or <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> in OSX, or by the menu `View -> Show Console`. This allows you to scroll through the history of your session and look for any errors. It is also the console to the internal version of Python 2.6 embedded in ST2, similar to the `>>>` that you see if you start Python from the command line, so you can use it to get all sorts of system information that way, if you know how to use [the API](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html) and, of course, [Python](http://docs.python.org/2.6/).