# Sublime-text-2: Nettuts-fetch and SFTP Package Conflict?

Tags: python, json, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Nettuts-fetch package stopped working. I followed '[Reverting to a Freshly Installed State](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/revert.html)' and then started to install packages. I started with Nettuts-fetch and re-started Sublime on each package install. The Nettuts-fetch worked fine until I installed SFTP. I removed SFTP and Nettuts-fetch worked again.

EDIT:

Fetch:file  - works as expected.

Fetch:Package - I can select a download location, the process stalls for a while, but does not show download animation processes (equals sign moving side to side), the download file is created with nothing inside and there is not a download complete confirmation.

Is there an error log file I can look for?

SUB EDIT:

["You can access the console by hitting `Ctrl-` `` ` ``"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555689/what-is-the-location-of-log-file-for-sublime-text-2-on-mac-osx)

Fetch.sublime-settings:

```
{
"files":
{
"jquery": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"
},
"packages":
{
"html5_boilerplate": "https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/zipball/master",
"phpmailer": "https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/archive/master.zip"
}
}
```

Console report after Fetch:

```
Exception in thread Thread-633:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
File "./fetch/downloader.py", line 46, in run
File "./fetch/downloader.py", line 209, in download_package
AttributeError: 'URLError' object has no attribute 'code'
```

and

```
Exception in thread Thread-638:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
File "./fetch/downloader.py", line 46, in run
File "./fetch/downloader.py", line 209, in download_package
AttributeError: 'URLError' object has no attribute 'code'
```

End EDIT

I presume there is a conflict between these two packages though I can not find anything relating to this on the Web? I do not know how to debug any further - help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the "conflict"?  What errors/problems actually occur?

Comment: I have edited my question with an explanation of what happens